# How to communicate between Ruby process and C process?

Tags: c, ruby, linux, networking

There is a C process, I need to call one function which will modify one C variables by Ruby program, I want to know how to do this, thanks!

Comment: You can interact with C by writing a C extension for Ruby, but that'll be its own process. I don't think you can do what you want without a fair amount of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use sockets?
You could even use threads or forks to avoid locking.

If you are on linux you should check out D-Bus, it allows communication through sockets too, but with some extra goodies ;)